# regex to not get the escaped quote

Tags: python, regex, escaping

The example string in python is `"sasi0'sada1\'adad2'theend"`

I want the single quotes which are not escaped, so quotes after 0 and 2 should be selected but not the quote after 1.

I tried `re.findall(r"[\d]'")` but I'm getting all tree quotes
Any help?

let me tell you the actual scenario!
 I'm writing a script to extract sql queries from code.
perl code:

```
ad.pl:$query = "Select *  from (Select ((select cast(sysdate as ts) from dual)||(select c_r from v\$r_limit where r_n=\'sessions\')||\',\'||(select c_u  from v\$r_l where r_n=\'t\')) as \"D,B,HH,AS,CT\" from dual)";
```

The regex:

```
re.compile(r'''(('|")(insert |update |delete |select )(.*?)(?<!\)(\2)(;?))''',re.IGNORECASE)
```

but the back reference is catching the escaped double quote.
so getting only half query

I don't think i can add extra backslash automatically to escape it as python fails to read \ in the first place to add other!
manually it's impossible to escape because thats huge project having lots of queries.
Any help?

Comment: '=\' ...............

Comment: @rock321987 I tried your suggestion, but still getting all quotes

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will work

```
(?<!\\)(?=')
```

*or*

```
(?=(?<!\\)')
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/blPPgD)**

If your requirement is as simple as you mentioned, then you don't even need look around. It can be simply written as

```
[^\\]'
```

The reason for regex not matching every quotes is because `python` is interpreting `\'` inside sting as a way to escape `'` because in python strings can be represented with both single and double quotes. So basically the left string to be matched is

```
sasi0'sada1'adad2'theend
```

[image]

This modified string does not contain any `\'`. So every `'` is matched. If you escape the `'` twice as

```
sasi0'sada1\\'adad2'theend
```

**What's the Solution then?**

Use raw string instead of normal string. This can be done by putting `r` in front of string before double quotes

```
r"sasi0'sada1\'adad2'theend"
```

Comment: thank you.I have extended the question! please have a look! can we automate adding extra back slash when ever we get single back slash followed by ' or "

Comment: @sasidhar513 mean only before `'` or `"`?

Comment: yes I guess. that's actual code cant add unnecessary backslashes!! I tried to add but failed!

Comment: @sasidhar513 i think it will be problematic..right now i can not say anything..maybe someone else can answer meanwhile..i will update once i get any answer

Answer (score 0):

`\'` in this case `\` acted as a escape for `'` so you need to escape the `'\'` as well like this `\\'`

```
re.findall(r"[^\\]'","sasi0'sada1\\'adad2'theend")
 ["0'", "2'"]
```

Comment: thank you.I have extended the question! please have a look! can we automate adding extra back slash when ever we get single back slash followed by ' or "

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be working for me. `\w((?<!\\)([\w']+))`